# как int преобразовать в char, при этом, чтобы можно было задать размер char в c++

Tags: c++

```
int c = (Year - 1) / 100 + 1);                                                                     
char century[1000] = c;                                                                    
send(newConnection, century, sizeof(century), NULL);
```

Пробовал так задать размер, но не получается, а если не задавать размер char, то на использование функции send компилятор ругается : "Аргумент типа << Char >> не совместим с параметром типа << Const char * >>".

Comment: `sprintf(century,"%d",c)`

Comment: Размер char в С++ фиксирован. Может тут шла речь о задании размера массива char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по написанному

```
int c = (Year - 1) / 100 + 1);                                                                     
char century[1000] = c;
```

вы хотите передавать столетие в виде строки. Это можно...

```
sprintf(century,"%d",c);
```

Но зачем вам пересылать 1000 байтов, если хватит и 4?

```
send(newConnection, &c, sizeof(c), NULL);
```

Только и принимайте на той стороне в переменную типа `int`.

Comment: 1000 байтов на случай, если пользователь захочет узнать век года, превосходящий 4 цифры.